# Is there a library or an malloc implementation, which allocates memory on heap as/like on stack?

Tags: c, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have a need to get heap memory in big chunks. And these memory chunks will be used as memory pools, and will not be released until the process exits.
So, the traditional `malloc` may be not as simple (nor as fast) as I want.
I think, a stack-like allocation (LIFO) would be more efficient than `malloc`.

Is there any existing libraries can do that?
Or should I write a new one for this purpose?

PS: I guess `obstack` best describes what I'm talking about. Any other candidate or introduction about `obstack`?

Comment: You make several unfounded assumptions in your question - just use regular malloc calls for memory allocation and everything will work fine. (And if it doesn't for some reason then you can always replace the malloc implementation later.)

Comment: Before you jump too far, have you tried some alternative malloc implementations? E.g. `tcmalloc`?

Comment: 'heap memory allocation as the way on stack' what do you mean by that ?

Comment: Could you explain why *exactly* you think that `malloc` might not be up to the task?

Comment: `malloc` may be up to the task. However, it (generally) locks the heap when allocating; and it has unnecessary flexibility （usually with more runtime overhead) in allocation and deallocation in my case, both of which could be optimized for performance reason.

Answer (score 1):

Listen to everyone else saying to just use `malloc` efficiently first, but if you really do need a region-based allocator, that can free stuff in big lumps, look to the Apache Portable Runtime library.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation):

> In C, the library function malloc is used to allocate a block of memory on the heap.

`malloc` will be plenty simple and fast.

Also, what does this mean?

> I think it will be OK to regard the heap memory allocation as the way on stack.

If you mean you want to use stack space for your memory pool, you'll be disappointed.  The stack is typically only a few MB (precise size depending on the machine and ?compiler).  Perhaps you have your ideas of stack and heap backwards?  The stack is where function frames, with arguments and local variables, go; the heap is where persistent, dynamically allocated memory goes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What I mean is that, I want a FILO memory allocation from heap, and memory on stack is allocated FILO, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the stack is FILO.  It's hard to make a more specific recommendation without knowing more about what you're trying to do, but if you know the max stack size you'll need, you can `malloc` it once and keep a pointer to the end

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` causes slowdown when it's called over and over again, like in the middle of a triply-nested loop.  If you're allocating a few large chunks with `malloc` and holding on to them for a long time, you're *already* using `malloc` efficiently.

For example, suppose you're working with 3D point data, and you have a `struct Point`.  If you worked with a `Point **` array and allocated *each point* individually, like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    points[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Point));
```

it would be slow.  But working with a block of `struct Point` instead of `struct Point *`, you figure out the size ahead of time and only call `malloc` once.

```
points = malloc(sizeof(struct Point) * size);
```

It's fine, because `malloc` only runs once.

Comment: I agree, and frequently calling the `malloc` and `free` may also result in a large amount of fragement blocks because the free blocks are connected by a freelist. However, that's the problem. Is it possible to reduce the overhead of a list? A stack-like allocation may be more efficient.